# Deserialize from string to object

Tags: c#, .net, json

I been stuck on this problem for long time now so I´m asking here.

I´m getting following error message:

```
"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'XXX' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly."
```

This is how my class looks like:

```
public class SSN
{
    public IDictionary<string,string> ssns { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the json-format:

[image]

Comment: how are you calling Newtonsoft? add those lines

Comment: try to create and serialize the object first to see how the json file should look like, then you'll figure it out! :)

Answer (score 4):

Your JSON contains **key** and **ssn** not **Key** and **Value** thus Dictionary won't work.
You need to create class like:

```
class SSN
{
    public string ssn {get;set;}
    public string key {get;set;}
}
```

And deserialize json to collection of SSN objects.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create class object to deserialize your json correctly like

```
class SampleClass
{
    public string ssn { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
}
```

Then you need to deserialize your json into `List<SampleClass>`  because you json is an array type that means its start from opening square brackets `[` and ends with closing square brackets `]` instead of curly brackets `{}`.

```
List<SampleClass> sampleClasses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SampleClass>>(json_string);
```

OR

```
List<SampleClass> sampleClasses = JToken.Parse(json_string).ToObject<List<SampleClass>>();
```